# Do not initialize the integer array in Struct

Tags: c, data-structures

IP'm making a calculator where he held two structures:
-IPv4: Contains an IP address of type "Address", the class of the IP and mask
-Address: Contains an array of 4 octets

```
typedef struct Address
{
    int *Octetos;

} Address;

typedef struct IPv4
{
    Address *IP;
    char Clase;
    Address *Mascara;
} IPv4;
```

I use 2 functions:
-CrearDireccion: Function that takes care of initializing an IP address
-CrearOcteto: Function that takes care of initializing the 4 octets of an IP

```
int * CrearOcteto(int num)
{
    int *octe=(int *)malloc (num*sizeof(int)); 
    octe[0]=0;
    octe[1]=0;
    octe[2]=0;
    octe[3]=0;
    return octe;
}
IPv4 * CrearDireccion(int Oct[])
{
    IPv4 *  instanciaDirec;
    instanciaDirec=(IPv4 *)malloc(sizeof(IPv4));
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos=CrearOcteto(4);
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[0]=Oct[0];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[1]=Oct[1];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[2]=Oct[2];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[3]=Oct[3];
    instanciaDirec->Mascara->Octetos=CrearOcteto(4);
    instanciaDirec->Clase='N';
    return instanciaDirec;
}
```

I get the following message when I run:
"Violation of segment (` core 'generated) "

Comment: An IPv4 address is 32 bits, so it can fit in a suitable sized integral type. You don't need dynamic allocation for this.

Comment: Check my post, I've done a lot of edits but it should be all now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `malloc()` the struct pointer `IP` before you try to access `Octetos`. Edit: And `mascara` too. There'r both pointers.

```
IPv4 * CrearDireccion(int Oct[])
{
    IPv4 *  instanciaDirec;
    instanciaDirec=(IPv4 *)malloc(sizeof(IPv4));
    instanciaDirec->IP = malloc(sizeof(Address));
    instanciaDirec->Mascara = malloc(sizeof(Address));
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos=CrearOcteto(4);
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[0]=Oct[0];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[1]=Oct[1];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[2]=Oct[2];
    instanciaDirec->IP->Octetos[3]=Oct[3];
    instanciaDirec->Mascara->Octetos=CrearOcteto(4);
    instanciaDirec->Clase='N';
    return instanciaDirec;
}
```

And don't forget to `free()` at some point ;)

And I would also re-design this, otherwise there's not point in passing a parameter;

```
int * CrearOcteto(int num)
{
    int i = 0; 
    int *octe=(int *)malloc (num*sizeof(int)); 

    while (i < num) {
       octe[i]=0;
       i++;
    }

    return octe;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was my problem, I did not know I had to reserve memory before initializing it.
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
instanciaDirec->Mascara->Octetos=CrearOcteto(4);
```

is dereferencing `Mascara` although it seems not to have been initialized.